# How to create a Class in java that has an array which can accept different objects

Tags: java, quarkus

I am using Quarkus framework. I am new to Java, so I don't have knowledge of libraries, so I just created these classes and returning them as response:

#### Code

```java
public class Person {

  private ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList();

}

public class Data {

  private String name;
  private String age;
  private String job;

}
```

#### Wanted

I want to print the object as JSON and omit all null values.

I want to create a list of people, but I want the attribute `job` only to appear when the person is more than 30 years old.

The final result should be like:

```json
    {
     data:
          [
           {
            "name": John,
            "age": 40,
            "job": Medic
           },
           {
            "name": Paul,
            "age": 29
           },
           {
            "name": Lua,
            "age": 20
           }
          ]
    }
```

#### Question

What is the way to do that?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried?  It would be helpful to know what library you are using and how you are calling that library.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to print your object as a json and omit all null values.

Comment: Converting Java objects to a JSON String can be done with existing libraries like jackson. see: [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson) - As for controlling whether null values should be included in the JSON or not, there are multiple ways to control that behavior: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields

Comment: Thank you @OHGODSPIDERS , jackson solved that issue for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Serialize an object to JSON using Jackson library

With the [hint of OH GOD SPIDERS's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764950/how-to-create-a-class-in-java-that-has-an-array-which-can-accept-different-objec#comment135333699_76764950), follow the answers to:

- [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)

These are the 3 steps to use Jackson:

1. add Jackson dependencies `jackson-core`, `jackson-annotations` and `jackson-databind` to your project, e.g. [to Maven](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#maven) POM

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Create an [`ObjectMapper`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to use for JSON mapping (generation/parsing)

```java
var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// optional configuration
```

3. pass your object instance to the suitable [`write..`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString-java.lang.Object-) method

```java
try {
    // convert object to JSON string and print it 
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person)
    System.out.println(json);
}
catch (JsonGenerationException | JsonMappingException  e) {
    // catch various errors
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**ℹ️ Note:** You need public getters so Jackson mapper can access and serialize to JSON.

### Configure desired serialization

#### Exclude null, empty or absent values

To exclude `null` values in written JSON, you can add the annotation [`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.15.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) to your properties:

```java
public class Data {

  private String name;
  private String age;
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  private String job;

  // getters and setters omitted

}
```

There are a few of similar ex-/inclusion options:

- `NON_ABSENT`

  > Value that indicates that properties are included unless their value is: null "absent" value of a referential type (like Java 8 `Optional`, or {link java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference}); that is, something that would not deference to a non-null value.
- `NON_EMPTY`

  > Value that indicates that only properties with null value, or what is considered empty, are not to be included.
- `NON_NULL`

  > Value that indicates that only properties with non-null values are to be included.

#### Conditional in-/exclusion

> I want to create a list of people, but I want the attribute `job` only to appear when the person is more than 30 years old.

Following are 2 ways to achieve this conditional serialization:

- [KISS] a "quick and dirty" solution
- [SOLID] a safe and maintainable design

##### [KISS] Simple modification of default getter

Assume the class `Data` is only used for the JSON-representation (what we call a DTO).
Then I would solve this simply by implementing a **conditional getter** like:

```java
public class Data {

  private String name;
  private String age;
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  private String job;

  public String getJob() {
    // exclude in JSON if 30 or younger
    if (Integer.valueOf(age) <= 30) {
       return null;
    }

    return job;
  }

  // remaining getters and setters omitted

}
```

**⚠️ Warning:** This modification breaks the conventional behavior of Java-getters. They should be free of conditions. Thus I added a comment to explain the "why" and kept the if-block easily removable to undo.

##### [SOLID] Add a custom accessor

Clean-code (expressive/additive) that follows design-principles (SRP/OCP) [as recommended by Reilas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764950/how-to-create-a-class-in-java-that-has-an-array-which-can-accept-different-objec/76765608#comment135336569_76765608) would:

1. keep `getJob` as your accessor, and
2. make a different method to provide the conditional check, call it `job` or `jobIfOver30`.

Example:

```java
private String job;

// other fields and getters omitted to focus on custom property serialization

@JsonIgnore  // 1. ignore the original property to keep accessor
public String getJob() {
  return job;
}

@JsonProperty("job")  // 2. conditional serialization with original name
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public String jobIfOver30() {
  if (Integer.valueOf(age) > 30) {
     return job;
  }

  return null;
}
```

**️ Benefit:** We don't need a comment and can invert the if-statement because the added method has

- a single responsibility (JSON serialization only) and
- a self-expressive name.

##### See also

Unfortunately not the case here, but when the condition depends only on values of the same property, you could use the `@JsonInclude` annotation with [`CUSTOM`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#CUSTOM) option as explained in:

- [@JsonIgnore with Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60422906/jsonignore-with-conditions)

Comment: As a recommendation, keep _getJob_ as your accessor, and make a different method to provide the conditional check, call it _job_ or _jobIfOver30_.

Comment: @Reilas Thanks for your [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) alternative. A solution to prefer in the long-run. Added it to my answer. Feel free to edit and improve, because I am not sure if `@JsonIgnore` is needed and applied correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the MappingCustomizer class is annotated with @Singleton, which means that there will be only one instance of this class created by Quarkus at runtime, and this instance will be reused throughout the application.

The customize method is implemented to customize the behavior of the ObjectMapper instance. In this case, the method sets the serialization inclusion to JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, which means that any properties with null values will be excluded from the JSON output.

By using this customization, any JSON output generated by the application will exclude any properties with null values, which can help to reduce the size of the output and make it more concise.

To use this customization in your Quarkus application, you can register the MappingCustomizer class with the ObjectMapperCustomizer interface, like so:

```
@Singleton
public class MappingCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }
}
```